# IAB Subscription Free-trial state

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

What's the right way of managing free trial state of a subscription?
I can't find anything about getting the state of a purchase, something like freeTrial = true/false or freeTrialDuration = 7, inside json info. When the user purchases the subscription with free trial, a transaction happens? What next when the free-trial expires? A new transaction?